# Send a text string as a png and embed it into an email

Tags: email, text, png, fedora, rhel

I am trying to create a CLI or script to use to send text string as a PNG, so it can not be seen as clear text on the internet.

Concept:

We have to send passwords to users but we do not want them sent as clear text. If we encode it as a png or jpeg it would make it harder for them to catch and decode.

Sample: string `T3sT!ng%2021`

output: png

[image: T3sT!ng%2021]

Comment: You should know that sending the text as an image is not secure.  You may want to consider other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) for that.

See examples [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label).